# -である form in written Japanese

Tags: grammar, formality, written-language

I have a question about the following example sentence:

*これは日本の会社のだ(である)。だが、 タイで作られた。*

From what I understand, である/だ and ます/です should not be mixed, and である is used in written language.

However, is following sentence correct in a formal/written context:

*これは日本の会社のである。だが、 タイで作られた。*

Or is there an alternative to the root/た/ない form that should be used instead? To me, it seems odd to mix -である (formal) with forms I consider casual (た、ない、etc.)

Answer (score 2):

である certainly marks the sentence as written-style, but in a style where you are using である, the normal past (perfective) would be ～た, 作られた; similarly, the negative would be 作らない and so on. These forms are not necessarily 'casual'.